# How to determine the cut-off per day in StackOverFlow?

Tags: support, time

I just want to know if SO has some sort of cutoff time per day? Is it fixed in one time (e.g. 00:00) or has some sort of related to when you have registered? (Scenario: For example I registered at exactly 2pm then the next day 2pm would be the cutoff and count as one day when I login). If not, what time is it? Is it applied to all SE Network?

Thank you.

Comment: I really knew that this is a duplicate but I don't know how to search the right keyword. Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's midnight UTC, for everyone. (For all actions such as the rep cap, votes per day etc.)

Comment: You would know this, wouldn't you? I imagine your rep counter at 12:01 suddenly jumping 200 points.